# Searching Outlook's Global Address Lists for multiple users with the same name

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have the following Powershell function:

```
Function outlookSearch{
    param([System.String] $searchString)

    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application] $galSearch = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

    $item = $galSearch.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries.Item($searchString)

    $script:name = $item.GetExchangeUser().Name
    $script:email = $item.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
}
$script:name = (Read-Host "Enter Name").Trim()
outlookSearch -searchString $script:name
$script:name
$script:email
```

As you can see when you enter a person's name it will search Outlook's Global Address List for it.  This works great for a single user, but if there is a person with the same name it will only return one.  I'm trying to figure out a way to return all the people that have the same name.  For example if there is two Alice Barns in the Global Address List it will return them both.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot do that in Outlook Object Model - you can loop through all GAL entries, but that will be too slow and will fail for large GAL containers.

In Extended MAPI MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you can use `PR_ANR` restriction to get all matches (that is what Outlook uses to show the list of ambiguous entries).

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use `RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx`

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx("joe user")
  Debug.Print AdrrEntries.Count & " names were returned by ResolveNameEx:"
  Debug.Print "------------"
  for each AE in AdrrEntries
  Debug.Print AE.Name
  next
  Debug.Print "------------"
```